# Is this the right place to ask about Jailbreaking ipod/iphone/ipad?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I'm wondering if this is the right place to ask about jailbreaking devices such as iPod, iPad, iPod, or how to root your Android phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Ventral:
Short answer is a resounding `**NO**`.
However, if you're asking how to build a framework that would *prevent* such jailbreaking, thats different and should be allowed.
In my opinion.

Comment: what if the question is about how jailbreaking the device works? Like how the process of jailbreaking is done in terms of which commands are run, how the new software is uploaded and so on?

Comment: Again, if this is about "how to jailbreak" then no. If it's "what happens in the kernel during jailbreak" or something like that, i.e. around the architecture of secure devices, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion: Only if you wish to implement a similar security solution and want to learn from the experiences of Apple or Google respectively.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Only if people are reversing to illustrate how not to build security or reversing to show how good security they have.  Like at blackhat 08 the stacksmashing talk showed how to get around ALSR and DEP to create an understanding of the strengths and weaknesses of the techniques.